# Converting an edittext value to an array of integers

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have raw folder with audio files from *a.mp3* to *z.mp3*.
I would like to play them programatically.

```
int[ ] myMusic = {R.raw.(edittext.getText(first letter),R.raw.(edittext.getText(2nd letter)
```

How do I make it loop for all my files?

Comment: This is won't compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly...

```
// Get from a Context, such as Activity 
Resources r = getResources();
String pkg = getPackageName();

// Extract and loops over text
String letters = edittext.getText().toString();
int size = letters.length();
int[] myMusic = new int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    // Get the R.raw.letter values 
    int resId = r.getIdentifier(letters.charAt(i), "raw", pkg);
    myMusic[i] = resId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to play music on whatever `String` you have typed into your `EditText`. Every character represents a file name in raw folder. So, you will have to use every characeter of `EditText` as a file name.

```
        int size = edittext.getText().toString().length();
        int[] myMusic = new int[size ];
        for(int i=0 ; i < size ; i++){
            int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(edittext.getText().toString().substring(i,i), "raw", getPackageName());
            myMusic[i] = resID;
        }
```